# Puppeteer - Handling multiple Window (same context)

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

There is very little information available and I've tried multiple things but there isn't a way to know apparently from Puppeteer if the Window is different, for example if I move manually a "tab" (not in headless) outside, this creates a new Window, there is apparently no way to be aware of it or have a concept of Windows in Puppeteer, can someone shed the light on this?

I don't wish to open more Chromium instances as I want to stick with the same profile (without copy), I want to deal with multiple Window (not tabs).

Selenium has a clear way of handling that by using getWindowHandle

Comment: Additionally, it seems that the "issue" could be fixed if ever there is way to simply open a tab in a specific Chrome window with Puppeteer, it doesn't seem that there is a way, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Puppeteer does not offer an API to do that. The underlying Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP) might offer what you need. See Target.createTarget's newWindow parameter https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target/#method-createTarget. It should be possible to get access to CDP and create a new window as following:

```
// pseudo-code, not tested if it works.
const client = await browser.target().createCDPSession();
const {targetId} = await client.send('Target.createTarget', { url: ..., newWindow: true });
const newTarget = await browser.waitForTarget(target => target.id === targetId);
```

It seems `newWindow` only has an effect in headful mode.

Comment: Thanks for that, afterward, it seems that I can't create/track specific Tabs from that Window, there is no reference to it. It's definitely a good first trail tho thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try  [puppeteer-cluster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tcortega/puppeteer-cluster).

This is what the example looks like:

```
const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster');

(async () => {
  const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
    concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
    maxConcurrency: 2,
  });

  await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
    await page.goto(url);
    const screen = await page.screenshot();
    // Store screenshot, do something else
  });

  cluster.queue('http://www.google.com/');
  cluster.queue('http://www.wikipedia.org/');
  // many more pages

  await cluster.idle();
  await cluster.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah I've tried extensively puppeteer-cluster library but it doesn't really fix anything, you still can't manage Windows.

Typical example is: in headful, I manually drag a tab out to create a new Window, how do I track it down afterward?

Comment: Have you  checked what events are available in browser.on() ?

Comment: Yeah, I've honestly tried I think literally all of them (that are relevant), the most notorious being on('targetcreated'), which offer zero indications if it's the same Window or not.

Comment: I'm starting to think that Puppeteer literally has absolutely no way of handling Chromium windows, I truly hope I'm wrong